# Select by location is empty when done through arcpy but returns values when done manually

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location

I have nearly 1000+ shapefiles that I need to (1) reproject, (2) covert to a raster, and (3) clip.  In order to make sure that there are values within the extent of concern, I put in a SelectByLocation_management logical check.  This is where I am having issues.  When I do the SelectByLocation, it comes up blank through the script.  However, when I do it by hand through the Selection>Select by Location toolbar, it selects the locations where there is an intersection.

Any ideas?

```
import arcpy, os
... arcpy.env.extent = "-1980501.4337461 2059002.55365216 -1940501.4337461 2090502.55365216"
... arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\\Data_Prep\\2013_Shape"
... shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
... projectOut = r"C:\\Data_Prep\\2013_Shape\\Project"
... rasterOut = r"C:\\Data_Prep\\2013_Shape\\Raster_Data"
... Extent_Polygon = 'Extent_Polygon'
... layer_files = r"C:\\Data_Prep\\2013_Shape\\Layers"
... error_list = []
... out_of_extent = []
... successful = []
... for shape in shapefiles:
...     print shape
...     # Process: Project
...     shape_name = os.path.join(projectOut, shape)
...     print shape_name
...     arcpy.Project_management(shape, shape_name, "PROJCS['USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic_USGS_version',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Albers'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-96.0],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',29.5],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',45.5],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',23.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]", "", "GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]", "NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE", "", "NO_VERTICAL")
...     print "%s was projected" %shape 
...     #determining if any cells are within extent
...     layernm = shape[11:-4]
...     layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shape,layernm)
...     arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layer, "INTERSECT", "Extent_Polygon","","NEW_SELECTION")
...     result = arcpy.GetCount_management(shape)
...     count = int(result.getOutput(0))
...     if count > 0:
```

Comment: GetCount() will always return > 0. Also, you are counting the feature class (should always return count of all features) not the feature layer (should return number of selected features or count of ALL features if NONE are selected). See help: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your script:

I assume "Extent_polygon" is an actual featureclass in your workspace. If it is, you should directly reference it. Further down in the code, you use "Extent_Polygon" as a string. Instead, you should reference the variable Extent_Polygon.

You can use the os.walk method to identify the folders and create variables.

You can use arcpy.SpatialReference(WKIDcode) instead of copying and pasting the whole text. See more information [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm). Make sure you insert the correct WKIDcode for your projection.

Layernm should use arcpy.Describe function instead of text indexes to create names. See more information [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/describe.htm)

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.extent = "-1980501.4337461 2059002.55365216 -1940501.4337461 2090502.55365216"
arcpy.env.workspace = ws = r"C:\\Data_Prep\\2013_Shape"
shapefiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
Extent_Polygon = r"path/to/dataset"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ws):
    for d in dirs:
        if d == “Project”:
            projectOut = os.path.join(root, d)
        if d == “Raster_Data”:
            rasterOut = os.path.join(root, d)
        if d == “Layers”:
            layer_files = os.path.join(root, d) 
error_list = []
out_of_extent = []
successful = []
for shape in shapefiles:
     print shape
     # Process: Project
     shape_name = os.path.join(projectOut, shape)
     print shape_name
     sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(WKIDcode)
     arcpy.Project_management(shape, shape_name, sr)
     print "%s was projected" %shape 
     #determining if any cells are within extent
     name = arcpy.Describe(shape)
     layernm = name.Basename
     print layernm
     layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shape, layernm)
     arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layer, "INTERSECT", Extent_Polygon,"","NEW_SELECTION")
     result = arcpy.GetCount_management(shape)
     count = int(result.getOutput(0))
     if count > 0
```

Comment: I'd use arcpy.da.Walk rather than os.walk.

Comment: I assume that has all the functionality of os.walk?

Comment: And it can walk into geodatabases and recognize their contents.

Comment: You need to use arcpy.Describe(layer).FIDSet to test for a selection. GetCount() will return count of all features if none are selected.